# How to modify subject output type?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following singleton:

```
public abstract class Store<Input, Output> {
    private BehaviorSubject<Input> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    private Observable<Output> observable; //also a singleton

    public final Subscription register(Subscriber<Output> subscriber) {
        if (observable == null) {
            observable = subject.compose(getTransformer()); //is this hot?
        }
        return observable.subscribe(subscriber);
    }

    public final void unregister(Subscription subscription) { //unregister }

    //applies operators to the original stream to transform Input -> Output
    protected abstract Observable.Transformer<Input, Output> getTransformer();

    public final void onNext(Input event) { subject.onNext(event);}
}
```

**Problem:** When I rotate the device or minimise the app the observable dies (aborts network execution). Is `subject.compose()` returning a cold observable, if so, why?.

I tried using `publish.autoConnect()` / `share()` to make it hot, now it doesn't die upon rotation... but the `BehaviourSubject` breaks. When I rotate the device and I don't get the first value upon subscription.

**How can I transform the output value of a `subject` and still have it behave as a `subject`? [SAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/feresr/RxStore)**

LOG:

> USER: *hits button to fetch from network*
>   D: Retrieving from
>   network... D: Network request executed successfully
>   D: Caching to memory
>   USER: *hits button to fetch from network again*
>   D: Retrieving from network...
>   USER: *pressed home button, app backgrounded*
>   D:.unsubscribe()

Comment: You apply operators that don't change the temperature of it, like `map`, `filter` and bunch of others. Your breakage may be due to something else not shown in the question, like the transformer or how you unregister in `onDestroy`.

Comment: Hi @akarnokd, here's my transformer https://github.com/feresr/RxStore/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/feresr/rxstore/JokesStore.java I updated my question, feel free to explore the provided project

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Subjects but how to keep an Observable running when the app gets paused: http://blog.danlew.net/2017/01/16/the-activity-lifecycle-vs-the-world/

Comment: The observabe lives in a singleton, and it's hot. It shouldn't go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I've been using Subjects wrong all along. Here's the correct version of what I wanted to implement above:

```
 public abstract class RxStore<Input, Output> {
        private BehaviorRelay<Output> relay;

        public final Subscription register(Subscriber<Output> subscriber) {
            if (relay == null) {
                relay = BehaviorRelay.create(defaultValue());
            }
            return relay.subscribe(subscriber);
        }

        public final void unregister(Subscription subscription) {
            if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        }

        public void execute(Input event) {
            buildObservable(event).subscribe(relay);
        }

        /**
         * @return the first or default value emitted to subscribers
         */
        protected Output defaultValue() {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * @return an buildObservable responsible of handling its own errors.
         */
        protected abstract Observable<Output> buildObservable(Input event);
    }
```

Edit:

I've found this approach very useful. I'm using this approach in prod and I've written an article about this:

https://medium.com/@FerRaviola/rxandroid-an-event-bus-on-steroids-9699e93eca98#.tqbxleo4h